# Two-Component distribution modelling

Tags: r, data-visualization, mixture-distribution

I am trying to plot a two-component mixture distribution $F_X(x):.7N(0,1)+.3N(3,1)$ with density

$$f_X(x) = {0.7 \over {\sqrt{2\pi}}} e^{−x^2/2} + {0.3 \over {\sqrt{2\pi}}}e^{−(x−3)^2/2} $$.

I have done the histogram for it but having trouble with plotting the true density,so far this is my code

```
x <- rep(na,2000)
mu1 <- 0
sd1 <- 1
mu2 <- 3
sd2 <- 1

for(i in 1:n){
    u <- runif(1,0,1)
    if (u < .7){
        x[i] <- rnorm( 1, mu1, sd1)
    }else
        x[i] <- rnorm( 1, mu2, sd2)
    }

hist(x,prob=T)
```

Comment: Rearranged the math a bit for you, making it a little clearer; hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
x <- seq(-3, 6, by=0.01)
fx <- 0.7*dnorm(x) + 0.3*dnorm(x,3)
plot(fx~x, type='l')
```

to get:

[image]